# golang 1.5/cassandra from debian repos?

Tags: go, cassandra, debian

I found golang 1.5 in Debian unstable/testing (which I need for cassandra gocql driver), has anyone installed this successfully without breaking the rest of Jessie, or should I just compile? Jessie has golang 1.3

Comment: While it shouldn't affect any other part of your system, just install it via the official instructions: https://golang.org/doc/install and there won't be any issues.